# jvc recorder .ced file

Tags: file-formats

I recorded some videos using a JVC recorder.  Now I am trying to upload those videos to my PC, but the format it .ced.  How do I play/convert this file to a different format on my pc?

Comment: how big is the file?

Answer (score 2):

According to [this post](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/940771?tstart=0) on Adobe's forums, the CED file is an attempt by the camera to save a corrupted video file that occurs when the memory card is not formatted in a way it can write video correctly.  It may or may not actually contain a usable video stream depending on what went wrong.  I couldn't find any PC tools that would open it reliably, but JVC might have something if you check with them.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to whack it with [MediaInfo](https://mediaarea.net/en/MediaInfo) (note the Windows GUI comes with adware, but the CLI version doesn't). If it can find stuff in there maybe we can save it. You probably can rescue it with [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/) if MediaInfo can find something in it. You can double check this with ffmpeg's ffprobe too.